# Changing JSP compiler version in glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am pre-compiling my JSP pages on deploy but keep getting these error:

```
 Caused by: org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: JSP
 Compilation Error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error
 in Javac compilation for JSP

 PWC6199: Generated servlet error: diamond operator is not supported in
-source 1.5   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator
```

Does anyone know how to change the compiler version and or settings to resolve this? I have already instructed glassfish to use JDK7 as java home like this;

```
asadmin set "server.java-config.java-home=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09"
```

But this does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-build the JSP page using Maven or Ant plugging i.e [jspc-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jspc/jspc-maven-plugin/usage.html). Not only do you get the benefit of debugging issue at build and staging phase, but you also get the speed of deployment and and elimination of frustration.

Comment: Could you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139152/glassfish-4-and-offline-jsp-compiler

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `compilerSourceVM` and `compilerTargetVM` properties of `jsp-config` correctly  for this to work. [Look here for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1750/beatx/index.html).

Comment: Thanks `Pangea`, I have tried this via the `glassfish-web.xml` held in my `WEB-INF` but still have the same error. Doing `java -version` produces the following also >>>>java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)). This is just dragging me nuts ;-)

Comment: The following in sun-web.xml worked fine for me for glassfish v2: `<jsp-config>
        <property name="compilerSourceVM" value="1.7"/>
        <property name="compilerTargetVM" value="1.7"/>
    </jsp-config>`

Answer (score 1):

Aravind's answer misses just an example. This is my working `WEB-INF\glassfish-web.xml` file:

```
<glassfish-web-app>
   <jsp-config>
     <property name="compilerSourceVM" value="8" />
     <property name="compilerTargetVM" value="8" />
   </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

I put this file inside the war.