# Glassfish 4.1.1 and offline JSP compiler (JSP and OSGI)

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi

As everyone knows jsp can't work with classes outside current osgi web archive bundle. This is a bug in GF. The developers of glassfish for workaround of this bug https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11208 offer to use offline jsp compiler (by other words to compile jsp files not during deployment time but during archive building time). Ok, and I used jspc-maven-plugin to compile my jsp during wab building.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.4.6</version>
 <executions>
     <execution>
         <goals>
             <goal>compile</goal>
         </goals>
         <id>compile</id>
     </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The jsp are compiled and I see their .classes in built web archive.

Now the problem - how can I make glassfish use my compiled jsp but not to compile it itself? Because I see that GF ignores compiled .classes and generate .javas and compile them itself.

**EDIT 1** What I make up to now:
1) I added to glassfish-web.xml

```
  <jsp-config>
        <property name="usePrecompiled" value="true"/>
        <!-- to see it doesn't generate .javas -->
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true" />
    </jsp-config>
```

2)And when I build my wab archive I have jsp classes in `WEB-INF/classes/jsp/...` However, I get exception that jsp file not found. When I `manually` move jsp classes to `WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp...` I see that container now sees these classes but I get

```
  StandardWrapperValve[default]: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/... (wrong name: jsp/...)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2370)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2154)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1542)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1925)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.osgiweb.OSGiWebDeploymentContext$WABClassLoader.loadClass(OSGiWebDeploymentContext.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.osgiweb.OSGiWebDeploymentContext$WABClassLoader.loadClass(OSGiWebDeploymentContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:654)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:202)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
```

So know this is the right path - org/apache/jsp. The question is how to make maven plugin to output to this direction?

**EDIT 2**
So I found the settings of this maven plugin -

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.4.6</version>
 <executions>
     <execution>
         <goals>
             <goal>compile</goal>
         </goals>
         <id>compile</id>
         <configuration>
             <packageName>org.apache.jsp</packageName>
         </configuration>
     </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, this is the final point but not result. As I get no exception, bute the returned http request is empty (blank page in browser). Seems I should use another maven plugin but which one?

Comment: To be clear, you are building WAB applications and not WAR applications, is that right?

Comment: @Steve C Please, see my edit.

Comment: If you aren't bound to use Glassfish as Container, Apache Karaf provides an alternative as pure OSGi container. Together with Pax-Web it also supports JSPs

Comment: @Achim Nierbeck But no Pax-Web no Apache Karaf are not complete JavaEE servers.

Comment: Which part are you missing? Surely not EJBs though you can use those with open EJB (tomEE)

Comment: @Achim Nierbeck Many parts :). One more thing - pax products are good. But support is bad. I remember I asked question about pax-exam. And I liked very much the answer which I got - why do you think that anybody should help you. See mailig list if it is interesting for you.

Comment: @JimJim2000 I'm sure all required JEE specs can be handled via Apache Karaf, that's why I did point you there. Regarding support of Pax project, well it's open source and therefore requires patience and thorough and respectful questions. The OPS4j community doesn't use Stack Overflow for Q&A and therefore all questions about OPS4j Pax projects should be directed to the OPS4j mailinglist. Since most people do voluntarily work on the projects you can't expect a Company driven support.

Comment: @Achim Nierbeck It seems to me that you try to change my opinion. But you shouldn't. I know that this open source project and never waited for "Company drivet support". But I needed help, because I couldn't understand how to use pax-exam. When I figured out I saw that the answer was so simple but no one answered me. After solving my problem and getting such answer from community I consider pax community as shareware.

Comment: @JimJim2000, to bad for you ... it certainly isn't shareware ... and you can't please 'em all ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to all steps which I did and explained in my edit it is necessary to modify web.xml file because plugin will add there mapping for servlets generated from jsp pages. So, the final settings are :

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.4.6</version>
 <executions>
     <execution>
         <goals>
             <goal>compile</goal>
         </goals>
         <id>compile</id>
         <configuration>
             <!-- package where the compiled jsp classes will be put -->
             <packageName>org.apache.jsp</packageName>
             <!-- the plugin adds servlets to this web.xml file -->
<outputWebXml>${project.build.directory}/web.xml</outputWebXml>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
         <target>8</target>
         <source>8</source>
         </configuration>
     </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**EDIT**
Finally I found out that the version of jasper in GlassFish 4.1 is not known or even can be modified -> I got exceptions that such method not found etc. So I ended with the following - I donwloaded the sources of this plugin and made it use the version of the jasper in glassfish. I did not do any modifications in source code of the plugin, only in pom.xml. So the final pom became:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <!--<parent>
    <artifactId>mojo</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <version>11</version>
  </parent>-->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <name>Maven Jspc plugin</name>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Jeff Genender</name>
            <email>jgenender@apache.org</email>
            <organization>Savoir Technologies</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.savoirtech.com</organizationUrl>
            <timezone>-7</timezone>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <contributors>
        <contributor>
            <name>Grzegorz Slowikowski</name>
            <email>gs@tiger.com.pl</email>
            <organization>Scott Tiger S.A.</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.tiger.com.pl</organizationUrl>
            <timezone>+1</timezone>
        </contributor>
        <contributor>
            <name>Pawel Pastula</name>
            <email>pablo@tiger.com.pl</email>
            <organization>Scott Tiger S.A.</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.tiger.com.pl</organizationUrl>
            <timezone>+1</timezone>
        </contributor>
    </contributors>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- from glassfish 4.1.1 modules folder we need:
        javax.servlet.jsp.jar
        javax.servlet-api.jar
        javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar
        javax.el.jar
        javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar
        javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar
        what versions of this jar you can find out in parent pom of glassfish
        http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/glassfish-parent/4.1.1/glassfish-parent-4.1.1.pom
        and in manifest file
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3-b02</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- we need this dependency as it contais tld files for core tag library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.jasper.glassfish</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.v201112011158</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.13</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When you will compile you bundle you will have to add the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3-b02</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Besides you will need to import some packages from glassfish to make it work.  So in result you can use precompiled jps files with glassfish, but you need to make some things before it. And as you see you link your code to GF.

The most important thing - you can work with classes from other osgi bundles in jsp! For those who work with osgi in java-ee this can be very important.  After doing all these steps I must conclude that `GF IS NOT SUPPORTED TO BE USED WITH PRECOMPILED JPS FILES` in spite of suggestions from the developers.

I hope at least one will appreciate all the solution, because it seems to me this is the first description in internet how to use precompiled jps pages with GF. By the way if you use osgi and it complains it can't find classes import the necessary packages.